# How to add new phtml block to existing container?

Tags: magento2, module

:)

I made a module in "app/code". Now I created the structure and made a new phtml file called "socialbuttons.phtml".

I created a file called "catalog_product_view.xml" and want to include my "socialbuttons.phtml" inside the container "product.info.social" there.

The Container does currently look like this:

```
<container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                </container>
```

I want to include my "socialbuttons.phtml" in the first row after "container". How do I do that? What do i need to put into my custom made catalog_product_view.xml?

I tried this now in my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
<css src="ShareExtension_socialshare::css/mycss.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.share" template="product/view/socialbuttons.phtml"/> 
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

This didnt work.